# How to resolve this issue in glassfish 3

Tags: java, glassfish

When tetsing my connection pool this error shows : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 org/postgresql/ds/PGConnectionPoolDataSource : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Unsupported major.minor version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/how-to-fix-java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-unsupported-major-minor-versi)

Comment: I just changed the Postgres driver from JDBC 4 to JDBC 3